# How do you unpack a list in a df and use addition on that list without making a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column to my df from a list and then add or minus numbers from each row of the df for that column.

```
list_of_num  = [1,2,3,4,5]
a_variable = 4

df["New_num"] = list_of_num + a_variable
```

desired output

```
New_num
5
6
7
8
9
```

I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
df["New_num"] = [num + a_variable for num in list_of_num]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can create `Series` out of `list_of_num` then add `a_variable`:

```
df['New_num'] = pd.Series(list_of_num) + a_variable
```

Or even more efficient (time complexity) seems to be use of numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

df['New_num'] = np.array(list_of_num) + a_variable
```

Comment: I already have a df I am adding a new column to the df from the list

Comment: not sure if I understand correct but I updated answer, may be you can try?

Comment: I cant seem to press the green tick but this worked great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List comprehension`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension). This will be quite performant:

```
In [2858]: l = [ i + a_variable for i in list_of_num]

In [2859]: l
Out[2859]: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

df['New_num'] = l
```